# Processing IDE data is not being sent to arduino properly

Tags: arduino, processing

I want to send processing IDE data to arduino. But led is not working. It worked fine once. But not working now :( Serial port name is exactly same in arduino as it is found by processing.

Processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class

void setup() 
{
  size(200,200); //make our canvas 200 x 200 pixels big
  String portName = Serial.list()[0]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}
         //send a 1

void draw() {
  if (mousePressed == true) 
  {                           //if we clicked in the window
   myPort.write('1');         //send a 1
   println("1");   
  } else 
  {                           //otherwise
  myPort.write('0');          //send a 0
  }   
}
```

Arduino code:

```
 char val='0'; // Data received from the serial port
 int ledPin = 13; // Set the pin to digital I/O 13

 void setup() {
   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // Set pin as OUTPUT
   Serial.begin(9600); // Start serial communication at 9600 bps
 }

  void loop() {
     //digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // turn the LED on
 if (Serial.available()) 
   { // If data is available to read,
     val = Serial.read(); // read it and store it in val
   }
   if (val == '1') 
   { // If 1 was received
     digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // turn the LED on
   } else {
     digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // otherwise turn it off
   }
   delay(10); // Wait 10 milliseconds for next reading
}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Have you used print statements to figure out which section of code is running in your Processing sketch? Have you determined whether your code is running on Arduino's side? Since you're calling `delay(10)` on Arudino, won't that cause the signals from Processing to build up since they're being sent every single frame?

Comment: @NurImtiazulHaque Both the Arduino and Processing code make sense. The only note is that you send the data in draw() which means the LED should be on for as long as the mouse is pressed. If you're having the issue with the LED, temporarily try to upload the *Examples > Basics > Blink* sketch and make sure that still works. There is an onboard LED to test. If you attached an LED manually to pin 13 double check the contacts are ok and the pins (cathode/anode) are connected the correct way

Comment: I'm using the on board LED (pin 13) Processing code is working fine. It is showing 0 and 1 simultaneously on mouse press and release. And serial port no. is also same. I've printed in processing to check. But data is not being sent to serial port. :( It worked once. I don't know what is happening :( @KevinWorkman

Comment: Blink program is also running fine in arduino.

Comment: @NurImtiazulHaque It's great the leds are working as expected, but strange the data is not being to the serial port. What happens when you send a ```1``` or a ```0``` via Arduino's Serial Monitor ? Does it work as expected ? (If it does, the issue is on the Processing side, if it doesn't the issue with the Arduino, in which case try a different USB port, USB cable or different Arduino altogether if the port/cable options don't change anything))

Answer (score 0):

## Processing

You can simply say `if(mousePressed)...`, there is no need to say `== true` (it's implied)

## Arduino

You're correct to check `if(Serial.available())` before trying to overwrite `val` with whatever character you read from there. However, the rest of your code inside `loop()` is executing regardless of this check. There is no reason to repeatedly write a pin to LOW or HIGH if it is already there. In fact, you will be more responsive if you only delay on loops where you find a character available for reading.

I'd recommend you add some print statements to your Arduino code so you can get a look at what you're reading.

Also, could it be that your hardware is connected improperly or that your LED is simply burnt out?